# Profiling Erlang/OTP release initialization

Tags: erlang, initialization, profile

I'd like to figure out how long parts of my Erlang/OTP release startup script (the .script and .boot files) are taking to run. Programming Erlang 2nd Edition, Appendix 3 says that loading OTP takes a second, loads 67 modules and starts 25 processes. This is used as motivation for running the VM without OTP. I'd like to quantify the load time for OTP and my modules in my setup. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

The `-init_debug` option provides some information if you pipe the debug prints through `ts`. Here's an example. Each timestamp is the number of seconds since the previous line was printed.

```
$ erl -init_debug | ts -i '%.s'
0.008446 {progress,preloaded}
0.001501 {progress,kernel_load_completed}
0.000576 {progress,modules_loaded}
0.000352 {start,heart}
0.001627 {start,error_logger}
0.011464 {start,application_controller}
0.024965 {progress,init_kernel_started}
0.000147 {apply,{application,load,[{application,stdlib,[{description,"ERTS  CXC 138 10"},{vsn,"1.19.4"},{id,[]},{modules,[array,base64,beam_lib,binary,c,calendar,dets,dets_server,dets_sup,dets_utils,dets_v8,dets_v9,dict,digraph,digraph_utils,edlin,edlin_expand,epp,eval_bits,erl_bits,erl_compile,erl_eval,erl_expand_records,erl_internal,erl_lint,erl_parse,erl_posix_msg,erl_pp,erl_scan,erl_tar,error_logger_file_h,error_logger_tty_h,escript,ets,file_sorter,filelib,filename,gb_trees,gb_sets,gen,gen_event,gen_fsm,gen_server,io,io_lib,io_lib_format,io_lib_fread,io_lib_pretty,lib,lists,log_mf_h,math,ms_transform,orddict,ordsets,otp_internal,pg,pool,proc_lib,proplists,qlc,qlc_pt,queue,random,re,sets,shell,shell_default,slave,sofs,string,supervisor,supervisor_bridge,sys,timer,unicode,win32reg,zip]},{registered,[timer_server,rsh_starter,take_over_monitor,pool_master,dets]},{applications,[kernel]},{included_applications,[]},{env,[]},{maxT,infinity},{maxP,infinity}]}]}}
0.004207 {progress,applications_loaded}
0.000136 {apply,{application,start_boot,[kernel,permanent]}}
0.302955 {apply,{application,start_boot,[stdlib,permanent]}}
0.000171 {apply,{c,erlangrc,[]}}
0.021488 {progress,started}
0.051776 Eshell V5.10.4  (abort with ^G)
```

In this example, it looks like `application:start_boot(kernel, permanent)` is the slow step since it takes about 300 ms.